# E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run sudo dpkg --configure -a to correct it

Tags: apt

I am trying to run following command

```
$ sudo apt-get install cron
```

but it gives following error

```
E: dpkg was interrupted,
```

Comment: The error is asking you to run a command... Have you done it?

Comment: Run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple and part of the full error message

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Therefore

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install cron
```